# How to load images in draw() function in p5.js?

Tags: p5.js

I'm writing a program in Processing using the p5.js language. The program displays an image in the background based on where the cursor is, using a voronoi diagram. There are over 150 images that I don't want to run loadImage() on repeatedly, which is why I'd prefer to use this method.

```js
function draw() {
  img_found = false;
  image(voronoi_diagram, 0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight);
  voronoi_diagram.resize(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  color_on_hover = voronoi_diagram.get(mouseX, mouseY);
  
  i = 0;
  while (!img_found) {
    if (colors_list[i] == color_on_hover) {
      displayed_img = loadImage("data/" + img_name_list[i] + "_f.jpg");
      image(displayed_img, 0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight);
      img_found = true;
    }
    else {
      i = i + 1;
      img_found = false;
    }  
  }
}
```

I assume this doesn't work because I'm unable to use loadImage() in draw(). What's my alternative then?

---

Another method I tried is saving each image to a list (, below,) then using "loadImage(i)" in draw(). This didn't work.

```js
  img_list = [];
  for(let i=0; i < img_name_list.length; i++) {
    append(img_list, loadImage("data/" + champion_list[i] + "_f.jpg"))
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It takes some time for the image to load, so it can't be rendered synchronously.

From [the docs](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/loadImage):

> The image may not be immediately available for rendering. If you want to ensure that the image is ready before doing anything with it, place the `loadImage()` call in `preload()`. **You may also supply a callback function to handle the image when it's ready.**

A callback would make sense for your use case:

```
function draw() {
  image(voronoi_diagram, 0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight);
  voronoi_diagram.resize(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  color_on_hover = voronoi_diagram.get(mouseX, mouseY);
  
  for (let i = 0; i < colors_list.length; i++) {
    if (colors_list[i] == color_on_hover) {
      loadImage("data/" + img_name_list[i] + "_f.jpg", (img) => {
        image(img, 0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight);
      });
      break; // stops the `for` loop
    }
  }
}
```

(I changed your loop structure to prevent an infinite loop in the case that the no matching color is found)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the loadImage load doesn't happen right away It will finish after the draw is over. you can use a var to be set in an onload()

```
var loadedImage=null;

loadImage("yourPath",(yourimage)=>{loadedImage=yourimage;});
image(loadedImage, 0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight);
```

not the best way. Your other way of loading them to a list would work if you had an index based on color like "255,34,55"=>loadImage(); and then find them by index.